# meanings of mov instruction with or without [] brackets around the source register in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers, mov

I'm a little bit rusty on Assembly. I want to ask you guys some questions.

1. Are these assembly instructions valid in NASM?
2. What are the differences, and when should we use them?

```
    mov EAX, EBX
```

vs

```
    mov EAX, [EBX]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
mov EAX, EBX
```

moves the value of EBX into EAX, while

```
mov EAX, [EBX]
```

moves the value of the address in EBX (so EBX must contain a valid address, otherwise you will get a segmentation fault) into EAX.

Comment: +1.  Congratulations on earning the right to vote!  (Your answer is a good one.)

Comment: And congratulations on earning the right to comment!  Not bad for one answer.

Comment: The grammar here is a bit confusing. "Moves the values of the address in EBX in EAX"? Do you mean "into EAX"?

Answer (score 8):

Can you read C?  If so then, given the prior definitions `int a, b;`, the first instruction is more or less equivalent to

```
a = b;
```

whereas, given the prior definitions `int a, *b;`, the second instruction is more or less equivalent to

```
a = *b;
```

except that EAX and EBX are registers rather than stack-resident variables.

There is much, much more that could be said, but the foregoing gives you the idea.

(Incidentally, NASM -- which admittedly I've not used in the past five years -- presents the arguments in reversed order as compared to GNU's assembler.  NASM puts the destination register on the left, the source register on the right, whereas GNU does the reverse.  NASM's convention is also called "Intel syntax," as compared against GNU's "AT&T syntax.")